# Names of tests in the mixed effects model

Tags: regression, anova, mixed-model

I try to report a mixed effects model analysis in R, but I'm confused about the naming for the test of the fixed effects. I want to confirm if I name the following tests correctly:

If I run `Anova(model, test = "F")` with the *car* package, is that an F test?

If I run `Anova(model, test = "Chisq")`, is that a Wald chi-square test?

If I test a fixed effect by comparing two nesting models using `anova(model1, model2)`, is that a Likelihood ratio test?

Comment: Yes on all counts it seems consulting the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/car/versions/3.0-8/topics/Anova).

Comment: @horseoftheyear Thanks!